# About scraping twitter data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How to extract followers of a person in twitter? For example, if I want to extract the followers list of Trump, how to do that using BeautifulSoup?

I have tried to extract followers list of Finn Balor in twitter.I took the url and applied the BeeautifulSoup object to it.But it is not giving the doc what i am seeing in "view page source". how to resolve this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("https://twitter.com/FinnBalor/followers")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
soup.find_all("div",{"class":"ProfileCard-content"})
```

this is the code i used.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: I have added the code what i used. The last line of coding is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter provides [REST APIs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs) you can use to interact with their service.

There is also a bunch of Python-based clients out there that we can use without re-inventing the wheel.

The one I like is  [Tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/). Tweepy has a excellent documentation you can follow to get twitter data.

Comment: can't we do scraping using BeautifulSoup for this?

Comment: yes you can but if there is rest api provided then why do you want to use scraping?And still if you want you can do this but you need to authenticate yourself to get data from twitter.....and authentication can be done by Scrapy framework or you can use Selenium  with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: fine. I understood now.Thank you so much